# How to start a GUI program after hibernation?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, systemd, wakeup, autorun

I love virtual desktops.  I keep half a dozen around, with every program I use regularly always at the ready.  This means I *dread* restarting my PC, since I have to setup everything again—specially since KDE broke session management with Plasma 5 (I'm running Kubuntu 15.10, Wily).

Hence, I love hibernation too.  But there's one annoyance: if I hibernate Chrome or Firefox, they take 20-30 *minutes* to thaw the next time I start my machine, all the while trashing the system with heavy disk reads, making it unusable.  Why?  Dunno.  Happens to many persons, some managed to solve it, I didn't.

So as a work-around I must close the browser before hibernating, and run it by hand next time around.  Being lazy like I am, though, I've decided to let the machine do it for me, but starting a GUI program from systemd's sleep scripts is proving difficult.

Killing Chrome gracefully is easy enough:

```
pkill --oldest chromium-browser;
```

as is starting it from a root terminal:

```
su -l chema -c chromium-browser
```

(with a small gotcha: if I try this with a KDE program, like kate, it appears with some default skin, instead of the actual theme I'm using)

But I haven't managed to make this last work during an actual wake up.  Here's a test script, using sleep instead of hibernation and kate instead of Chrome, for faster testing:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Closes Chrome during hibernation to prevent crazy disk reads on thaw
# Systemd version, copy to /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ and chmod +x

if [ $1 = pre ] && [ $2 = suspend ]; then
    killall kate;
fi

if [ $1 = post ] && [ $2 = suspend ]; then
    echo "Running kate."
    su -l chema -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 kate" & 2>>/tmp/wake-log
fi
```

Kate is killed on sleep alright, but never started on wake, even though "Running kate." does appears on syslog.

I also tried with `runuser -l chema -c kate`, but that always fails with *QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display / Abort (core dumped)*, even after a `xhost local:`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Get an SSD -- wakeups for Chrome and FF will be "SSeamleSSD" ;)

Comment: Haha, just got one, as a matter of fact.  Just waiting on the adapter tray to arrive (from China, mind you) to replace the DVD with it.  But at 500MBps I'm just doubling the read speed, so I don't expect it to solve my thawing woes.  10 minutes is still an awfully long takeoff.